# Counting number of occurrences of Array element in a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD1 with Key-Value pair of type `[(String, Array[String])]` (i will refer to them as (X, Y)), and a Array Z[String].
I'm trying for every element in Z to count how many X instances there are that have Z in Y. I want my output as ((X, Z(i)), #ofinstances).

```
RDD1= ((A, (2, 3, 4), (B, (4, 4, 4)), (A, (4, 5)))
Z = (1, 4)
```

then i want to get:

```
(((A, 4), 2), ((B, 4), 1))
```

Hope that made sense.
As you can see over, i only want an element if there is atleast one occurence.

I have tried this so far:

```
val newRDD = RDD1.map{case(x, y) => for(i <- 0 to (z.size-1)){if(y.contains(z(i))) {((x, z(i)), 1)}}}
```

My output here is an RDD[Unit]

Im not sure if what i'm asking for is even possible, or if i have to do it an other way.

Answer (score 1):

So it is just another word count

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", Array("2", "3", "4")), 
   ("B", Array("4", "4", "4")),
   ("A", Array("4", "5"))))

val z = Array("1", "4")
```

To make lookups efficient convert `z` to `Set`:

```
val zs = z.toSet

val result = rdd
  .flatMapValues(_.filter(zs contains _).distinct)
  .map((_, 1))
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

where

```
_.filter(zs contains _).distinct
```

filters out values that occur in `z` and deduplicates.

```
result.take(2).foreach(println)
// ((B,4),1)
// ((A,4),2)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick answer!

Lets say i got the answer: ((A, 4), 2) and ((A, 1), 3)
If i now wanted to multiply all A values with each other (and dont care about the 2nd element in the Key), so that A =2*3 would i just go:
result1 = result..map{case (x, y) => ((x._1), y)}.reduceByKey(_ * _) ?

Also, if i wanted to get the a Key Value pair even when they Value was 0, how would i manage to that?

Comment: Another question: 
In the _.filter(zs contains _).distinct the first _ refers to a Key-Value pair, but the second _ refers to the Value, i dont quite understand why they refer to different things here. Could you try to explain this?